# Sending SMS from Mobile to PC and vice versa using a programming language without GSM Modem

Tags: java, c++, mobile, sms

I was wondering if there is a way you can send an sms from mobile to pc using any language(preferably Java) without the use of gsm modem. I guess there should be some other way or some SMS API but my research didn't return anything. I want to use it for my final project at uni. If SMS is not an option, can you think of some other way of sending info from mobile to pcwithout having any internet connection. I know it sounds crazy, but i want to know from the experts if there is any way.

Comment: SMS without modem... No. I know companies are offering "SMS" APIs, but it's only a service using a modem in their backoffice. SMS architecture uses GSM transportation, you will not have the choice.

Comment: If you could connect to your GMail box without internet , then you can achieve your objective :p .

Comment: haha i guess there is no way to send information from mobile to pc without the use of internet or cables. My final year project idea is ruined :D

Comment: The question is what exactly are you trying to do. Perhaps bluetooth connection would be suitable here?

Comment: Well I have thought of a Facebook SMS project, which basically allows you without having internet to update your fb status, check on new messages, send messages and stuff using a specific syntax for every command. So when you are at university for example and you are eager to check your fb, you can do it. There will be an application running constantly on your home pc and waiting for an SMS to be received, get processed, fetch stuff from fb and then send it back to the sender.